# SQL count across two tables

Tags: sql

I want to return the rows in the Base table that have an inventory over a certain count.

Something like this, but having difficulties...

```
SELECT b 
FROM Base b, Inventory i
WHERE COUNT(b.brand = i.brand) > 2
```

This should be returned:

```
brand  | model |
----------------
ford   |  T    |
chevy  |  X    |
```

.

```
Base
----------------
brand  | model |
----------------
toyota |  R    |
ford   |  T    |
chevy  |  X    |
```

.

```
Inventory
---------
brand  |
---------
toyota |
ford   |
ford   |
ford   |
toyota |
chevy  |
chevy  |
chevy  |
```

**Edit History**

- *I've updated the Base table to include further rows required*

Comment: Most (if not all) the answers would probably have worked before. I think now, (currently) all are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your query, It looks like you're trying to do a join, and then a count.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Base b
INNER JOIN Inventory I
ON (b.brand = i.brand)
GROUP BY i.brand
HAVING COUNT(i.brand) > 2
```

---

An alternative (that I could think of), would be to use a nested select:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Base
WHERE brand IN (
        SELECT brand
        FROM Inventory
        GROUP BY brand
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
              )
```

Comment: Use In `operator`. `=` will throw error if more than one row returned by subquery

Comment: @NoDisplayName: Like that. (I've not used SQL for a *long* time) - but I know the first works anyway. Have tested it and now it works. Cheers for the heads up :)

Comment: Thanks, used the nested select for my jpa query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and `having` clause to filter the `brand` having `count >2` Try this.

```
select * from base b where exists(SELECT 1
FROM Inventory i
where b.brand=i.brand
group by brand
having COUNT(1) > 2  )
```

Comment: Although I would tend to agree with this, what happens if the OP requires info from the *base* table? Then you'd have to do a nested select if you were to do this (although, that would still probably be easier to understand)

Comment: @jbutler483 - He is just selecting brand

Comment: OP may have just altered their requirements ( from inclusion of another column in the base table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use`GROUP BY`to group the records and use`HAVING`to filter the groups like this:

```
SELECT b.brand, b.model
FROM Base b
JOIN Inventory i 
ON b.brand = i.brand
GROUP BY b.brand, b.model 
HAVING COUNT(i.brand) > 2
```

Comment: OP may have just altered their requirements ( from inclusion of another column in the base table)

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) with an [`HAVING`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) can do the trick. 
You can do something like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25bda/1)

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Inventory i
INNER JOIN base b 
ON b.brand = i.brand
GROUP BY i.brand
HAVING COUNT(i.brand) > 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25bda/1/0)**:

```
| BRAND | MODEL |
|-------|-------|
| chevy |     X |
|  ford |     T |
```